# Javascript recursion within a class

Tags: javascript, class, recursion

I am trying to get a recursion method to work in a class context. Within my class I have the following method:

```
    countChildren(n, levelWidth, level) {
    if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
        if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) {
            levelWidth.push(0);
        }
        levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
        n.children.forEach(function (n) {
            this.countChildren(n, levelWidth, level+1);
        });    
    }
    // Return largest openend width
    return levelWidth;
}
```

However, when I use this method (which worked before when I just used it as `function countChildren = ...`) it can't... find (?) itself: `Cannot read property 'countChildren' of undefined` at the recursion.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That's because the callback for `forEach` has it's own scope, and sets the value of `this` to something other than the class.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem arises because within your loop, `this` gets redefined to the inner function scope.

```
countChildren(n, levelWidth, level) {
    var self = this; // Get a reference to your object.

    if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
        if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) {
            levelWidth.push(0);
        }
        levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;

        n.children.forEach(function (n) {
            // Use "self" instead of "this" to avoid the change in scope.
            self.countChildren(n, levelWidth, level+1);
        });    
    }
    // Return largest openend width
    return levelWidth;
}
```

Comment: Good catch @krillgar.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the `that = this` trick. There are constructs that are part of the language for this particular use case, mainly `.bind()` and arrow functions in ES6.

Comment: @SumiStraessle I'm not a fan of `this` at all. OP seems to be newer to Javascript, so I didn't want to confuse them. I see you answered with that, so I won't append to my answer.

Comment: No worries. I like arrow functions to solve the scoping hell problem, it also makes the code more readable.

Comment: @SumiStraessle I haven't spent much time with them as my last project was server side. I'll take a look at using them with TypeScript next time I'm doing client side work as my enterprise work often still unfortunately needs to target IE.

Comment: Good luck with IE ! :-D

Comment: every single array function takes a last argument called this, which decides what the value of this will be inside the function. that's more useful than self =this. 
just don't use arrow function, cause they override the 'this'.

Answer (score 15):

Try binding the method in the constructor.
Also, by using an arrow function for your `forEach`, you keep the scope of the class' `this`.

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor(){
        this.countChildren = this.countChildren.bind(this);
    }

    countChildren(n, levelWidth, level){ ... }


    countChildren(n, levelWidth, level) {
        if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
            if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) {
                levelWidth.push(0);
            }
            levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
            n.children.forEach( n => { // arrow function do not need to rebind this
                this.countChildren(n, levelWidth, level+1);
            });    
        }
        // Return largest openend width
        return levelWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: This may work, but I found @krillgar's answer to be the most straightforward. Thank you for replying.

Comment: See my comment on the `that = this` trick. Since you use classes, you are using ES6 syntax, which means you have access to arrow functions, which do not rebind the scope of `this`. Try it too. Your code will thank you.

Comment: Hmmm... okay I will have a second look then

Comment: In case you want [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: I tried it and this works too. I agree it looks nicer.

Answer (score 1):

the variable `this` Gets redefined within:

1. the inner scope of a for loop
2. within a inline function declariation
3. within asynchronous function calls.

I agree with krillgar with the declaration of self.
it fixed my problem with an asynchronous call.

```
obj.prototype.foo = function (string){
   var self = this;
   if(string){ do something }
   else
   setTimeout(function(){
     self.foo("string");
     }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The this inside the foreach than the this in the class. In your case, this refers to the current element being iterated.

you need to bind the scope.

```
n.children.forEach(function (n) {
   this.countChildren(n, levelWidth, level+1);
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using `.call()` to invoke the function. That way you can specify the context directly.

Like this:

<strike>`this.countChildren.call(this, n, levelWid);`th, level+1</strike>

Edit:
Noticed my error, what you should really do is bind the anonymous function:

like this:

```
  n.children.forEach(function (n) {
    this.countChildren(n, levelWidth, level+1);
  }.bind(this));
```